# Will Sergius Turrianus ever stop giving you quests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the College of Winterhold, the professor Sergius Turrianus can give you a quest [where you go to a random person and pick up an item](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Pick-Up) (as well as a quest where you give him some soul gems). My question is: is it possible to ever "complete" these quests, or will he continue to give you them forever (even after he starts giving you the same people over again)? By complete I mean he will have no more fetch quests left for you to do and will never give you the chat option to do them again.

Also, if it is possible, what is the "ending" dialouge he gives you in congragulations (if there is one)?

Comment: i don't there is an end, i think this is apart of the radial quest system the game employs where quests are endlessly generated, such as the bounty hunts the Holds have

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, he won't stop. These are [Radiant quests](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Radiant) and are part of why Bethesda advertised "infinite quests" in the hype for Skyrim's release. They are infinitely generated, though repetitive.

Answer (score 2):

There's no end. Same as Delvin's and Vex's quests.